# New window in old frame paint cracks

Tags: bathroom, windows

The paint from an old window frame is separating from a new window that was installed there. It’s pretty much all the way around the window, not just one spot. Also some paint coming off the outside of the frame but hard to say whether that’s new. The room is a new bathroom that was added.

Moisture? Expected problems with paint bonding across different surfaces? Or big problems? Thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing what happens when substrates are not properly prepared.  The wood in the first picture (exterior side) was not properly primed and the paint is flaking off.

You can try scraping the area to remove the rest of the loose paint, prime, apply something like Peel Bond which essentially acts like a glue for loose, flaky paint and then apply some new paint over top.

As far as the two pictures from the interior, it appears that gap between the window and trim needs to be caulked. Caulking is designed to stretch and flex. People tend to think that they can fill small gaps like that with paint and it may last a short while but paint is not designed to fill holes, gaps or cracks.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the case for both the inside and outside pictures? The first one to be clear is the outside-facing frame. Second two are the inside, where window meets sill. Thanks!

Comment: The inside looks fine. I don't see any adhesion issues just that the gap from window to the trim should be caulked. Paint is not intended to fill gaps and cracks.

Comment: Should it have been caulked to begin with, you think? Im finding various problems with the contractor who did this work.

Comment: It would depend on what the contractors scope of work included. If it was me installing the window I would not have walked away without caulking that, to me, it looks unprofessional. Lucky for you, caulking isn't very hard and is extremely cheap.

Comment: I paid him a fortune lol. Well, at the very least I’d rather the answer be poor workmanship than more fundamental problems with my house. Appreciate you!

Comment: Review your proposal/scope of work and make sure this was/was not included and go from there.  The problems you're seeing (from my perspective) are purely cosmetic and no need for concern. They should be addressed but no need to panic.   If this helped you consider ticking the check mark.